# Arrangement of Necklace beads and members

Tags: combinatorics, word-problem

1. How many round necklace can be  made using $10$ different color beads?
2. If $10$ members are to be seated on a round table then how many
   arrangements are possible?

**Answer:**

First problem has got answer $=9!/2$ and second $=9!$

why in first we need to divide by $2$?

Comment: The necklace can be turned around giving the other half of the arrangements. Hard to do this with a table and remain seated ;-)

Comment: HARD but still possible?

Comment: Still logic is not clear to me I know we can turn it round to make another arrangement but that is what we need I mean we need total number of arrangements why we are hiding them?

Comment: Each arrangement in the necklace is actually two arrangements at the same time. This makes the two indistinguishable. The same is not true for a table with persons. You'll notice it if your head points to the floor.

Comment: My argument is same, they are two but we are enumerating them not hiding them?

Comment: and by giving 9! as an answer you also ruled out the rotation. If there were a lock in the necklace or a marker on the table, you'd get 10! and 10!/2 as an answer because the solutions can't be rotated any more. If the beads clearly had a front- and a backside, you couldn't turn the necklace without noticing a difference. Then the answer would be 10! (or 9! without a lock) as well.

Comment: In combinatorics, I thought a [necklace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Necklace_(combinatorics)) often could not be turned over but a bracelet could be

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the axes of symmetry. The necklace and desk are symmetric to rotation of 36 degrees. This means we need to divide the number of permutations (10!) by 10. (360/36)

The necklace is further symmetric to rotation of 180 degrees around an axis passing through it. This means we need to divide the number of permutations (10!) by 10 and then by 2

Why are we dividing - let's say we order the beads as yellow, green,..., red and then while you're not looking we rotate the chain so we now see it as red, ...., green, yellow. You can't tell if we originally had red, ...., green, yellow, or if we rotated it. Therefore the two arrangements are equivalent.

Comment: Very good reasoning for goof like me.Thanks dear!